# How to generate random number between 0 and 1 without 0 and 1 in R?

Tags: r

I want to generate random numbers using runif(n=1,min=0,max=1) in R, but I don't want the point 0 and 1, how can I modify this to achieve my goal?

I  think it really generates 1 some way, see my code here

```
randomDim = round(runif(1)*3)+1;randomDim

  # [1] 4
```

Comment: 0 and 1 are the defaults, just do `runif(1)`

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with `runif` and everything to do with `round`. The *Details* section of `?round` explains how you can get a result of 4.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, any advice to fix this problem?

Comment: If you are indeed looking to generate a random integer in the interval 1-3 (which your code suggests) `sample(1:3,1)`will do it for you.

Comment: What problem? Both `round` and `runif` are doing what they're documented to do, and `runif` does by default what you ask in your question.

Comment: @Pewi, I think you should post your comment as an answer.  It's the answer to the OP's real question ...

Answer (score 20):

The documentation for `runif` states:

> ‘runif’ will not generate either of the extreme values unless ‘max
>        = min’ or ‘max-min’ is small compared to ‘min’, and in particular
>        not for the default arguments.

Therefore, it is already guaranteed not to generate 0 or 1, so there is no modification needed.

Comment: I think it really generates 1 some way, see my code here

randomDim = round(runif(n=1, min = 0, max = 1)*3)+1;randomDim
[1] 4

Comment: Why does this suggest that it generates 1? The output 4 would be the result if it generated anything larger than 2.5/3.0 = 0.833...

Comment: `range(runif(n = 1e8))` gave me `[1] 4.889444e-09 1.000000e+00`, so 1 is possible...

Comment: @DominicComtois, not quite (I think): `1-max(runif(n = 1e8))` is  3.958121e-09

Comment: @DominicComtois: `1.000000e+00` != `1.0`. `set.seed(21); r <- range(runif(n = 1e8)); sprintf("%20.20f", r)`

Comment: Ok, that's convincing evidence ;)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this, simply?

```
runif(n=1, min=1e-12, max=.9999999999)
```

Comment: That's unnecessary. `runif` doesn't include the extremes by default.

Answer (score 2):

By popular request:
`sample(1:3,1)` might be the answer to your problem.
It has nothing to do with `runif` but provides any one of the integers commonly referred to as one, two and three, with a respective probability of 1/3.

Answer (score 2):

try `sample(1:9, 1000, replace = TRUE)/10`

so you're randomly generating numbers from 1 to 9 and using fractions on it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option to those listed above is to generate your numbers using a Beta distribution.

A Beta distribution with `shape1=1` and `shape2=1` parameters will give you a flat (i.e., uniform) distribution that is mathematically limited at 0 and 1 (i.e., cannot possibly take on either value).

`rbeta(n, 1, 1)`

also as an aside how much of the result you do not like stems from the fact that you are using the `round()` function?

I ask because if you were to run `round(.97*3)+1` you would return a value of `4`. Similarly if you were to run `round(.005*3)+1` you would get `1`. Both `.97` and `.005` *are* legal values that `runif()` could plausibly return. So your unwanted results may not be related to `runif()` returning values at its default extremes (which as has been pointed out in other answers are not included in the range of values sampled from).

In any case, if you are still unconvinced and want something instead of `runif`, the beta distribution with shape parameters equal to 1 will mathematically ensure that you can never get a 1 or a 0, and with that parameterization you will have an equal chance of drawing any value between 0 and 1 in a `rbeta(n,1,1)` distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is some discussion under *Brent Kerby*'s answer if in doubt you can always check the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/nmath/runif.c):

```
double runif(double a, double b)
{
    if (!R_FINITE(a) || !R_FINITE(b) || b < a)  ML_ERR_return_NAN;

    if (a == b)
    return a;
    else {
    double u;
    /* This is true of all builtin generators, but protect against
       user-supplied ones */
    do {u = unif_rand();} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
    return a + (b - a) * u;
    }
}
```

So the algorithm "in case" rejects all values smaller or equal to zero and greater or equal to one... Exact zeros and ones are impossible. Values close to them up to floating point precision are possible as noted by *Ben Bolker*.